# C# Task.continuewith that's dependent on previous Task.Result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am wondering how you would use Task.ContinueWith() method that invokes an Action where the int is the result of the first task. Here's same code samples:

```
Task<int> first_task = GetFirstTask();
Action<int> next_action = (result_from_first) => { //do stuff };
first_task.ContinueWith( () => next_action(first_task.Result) );
```

Error:

```
Error   81  Delegate 'System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>>' does not take 0 arguments
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Task<int> first_task = GetFirstTask();
Action<int> next_action = (result_from_first) => { //do stuff };
first_task.ContinueWith( first => next_action(first.Result) );
```

should do it

Comment: This is better than referencing first_task inside the continuation delegate, as it avoids creating an unnecessary closure.

Comment: this and you can easily decouple/refactor the action into it's own (static) method ;)

Comment: How does C# know "first" is "first_task"?

Comment: I made a typo in my answer. This is correct. You need to add something (anything). It's a lambda expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397687.aspx. In plain English, you are saying, "let's call the first task `first` and then do something" and the something may or may not reference `first`. In this case it does.

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon `ContinueWith()` takes an `Action<Task>`, which means a function that takes in one `Task` and doesn't return a value. `first => next_action(first.Result)` is a lambda representing `void function( Task first ){ next_action(first.Result); }` and this function is called with the `first_task` as the parameter.

Comment: I understand that the lambda statement: (first)=>{ next_action(first.Result)}; is basically a nameless function that takes a Task<T> argument. I am not sure how would the compiler know that first is now "first_task" ?

Comment: the implementation of `ContinueWith` takes care of this - in case you wonder: this makes sense if you want to check for exceptions or if the task got canceled (indeed you should!)

Comment: What would the code look like if I were to explicitly create the a "next_task" variable and use it in ContinueWith()? Task next_task = new Task( (result) => { next_action(result); }); first_task.ContinueWith(next_task); ? I get the error that Task doesn't take argument and no overload method for ContinueWith()

Comment: Well the compiler tells you all - this is not going to happen as there are no method-overloads for this. You can find the information using intelli-sense or on msdn: [`Task.ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Task.Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.task(v=vs.110).aspx)